# How to create a button to select all 'none' values in bundle options in Magento 1.9?

Tags: php, jquery, magento, bundle

I want to have two buttons for bundle products just under pricing, "Buy Barebone" "Add to cart". 
By clicking on Add to cart button it should simply add all the pre-selected bundle options to the cart. However, clicking on Buy Barebone should select all 'none' values available in all the bundle options.

This would allow the user to buy either just single primary product or add/remove other components.

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: IMHO simplest solution will be check all available 'none' values and submit add-to-cart form (by javascript)

Comment: I've added two buttons as shown in link 'Buy barebone' and 'Configure it yourself'. I would like to add just the first bundle option 'Barebone' to cart by clicking on 'Buy barebone' here's the link: http://62.100.204.242/~beta3d/bundle-test.html